# find the row/column in a spritesheet using the frame number

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have sprite sheet, and I know there are 4 columns of sprites, and n number of rows. So how will I find the row/column of a particular frame?

I tried:

```
function drawSprite(num){
        var row = Math.floor(num/col_count)+1;
        var col = parseInt(num%col_count); // forget about parseInt for now
        console.log("Row:"+row+"   Col:"+col);
    }
```

for `frame 7` it works perfectly, giving `Row:2  Col:3`, but for `frame 8`, it gives `Col:0`, is there a way to get it to give 4, without a ternary condition checking in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rows and columns should be zero-based, with `(0,0)` being the top-left corner. Remove the `+1` on the `row` line, then you'll be able to multiply the coordinates by the frame size.

Comment: The top-left corner of the sheet is `(0,0)`, so you need that zero.